# One word to describe a person who fights for a righteous cause

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe a person who fights for a righteous cause. There is patriotic but that is a person who fights for ones country.

Comment: The most common term in the US (and perhaps England) is "crusader", though that has some (fairly weak) religious connotations which you may wish to avoid.  But you can Google `crusader synonym` to get some other ideas.  Do keep in mind that any term you choose will tend to have picked up "extremist" connotations.

Comment: @HotLicks Agreed about the religious overtones. I suppose that comes with the territory when one fights for “righteous” causes that aren’t universally deemed “righteous”. Both sides of any controversial topic qualify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Paladin

1. A heroic champion (especially a knightly one).
2. A defender or advocate of a noble cause. (A defender of faith).
3. Any of the twelve Companions of the court of Charlemagne (of whom is highly associated with chivalry).

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paladin

## Crusader

Figurative sense of "vigorous campaign for a moral cause or against a public evil" is from 1786.

Originated in reference to the medieval expeditions undertaken by European Christians for recovery of the Holy Land from Muslims and sometimes is extended to other religiously motivated expeditions.
https://www.etymonline.com/word/crusade